# Make AJAX request after css or layout on the server have changed

Tags: css, ajax

Modern phone users can keep a web page open in a browser tab for days. They can return to the tab anytime and initiate some ajax requests receiving html from the server.

The server can experience some changes during this period. Html layouts can be changed, css classes can be added or renamed.

What is the most common solution to this?

1. Send some response for force reloading the page.
2. Keep old versions of layouts and send them to old users.
3. Attach `style` and `script` tags to response. This can affect the rest of the page.

Comment: 2 would probably be the most complex option to implement (although I see some bigger web-apps doing this, for example the web version of WhatsApp gives you an alert when there is a "new version", and ask if you want to update now.)

Comment: With 3, you could at least disable the already existing stylesheet embeds in the document, before you add the new/modified ones. But the same thing isn't as easy with scripts. Unless you have a very "sophisticated" user base demanding a more complex solution, I would probably just go with option 1. Easiest to implement, and the least potential for trouble/unexpected side effects.

Comment: 4. Keep styling and markup on the page itself, and only exchange *data* in AJAX requests/responses.  Ensure non-breaking changes to that data as best you can, but in the event that there is a breaking change (which should be very rare) handle the error client-side and suggest the user reload the page.